# How can I get all checkboxes checked values from all the pages in a jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

How can I get all check boxes checked values from all the pages in a jQuery DataTable

Tried in different ways

```
$('.btnprimary').click(function () {

   $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){

        if(this.checked){
            alert($(this).attr('data-voucgerid'));
        }
    });
});
```

I need to get all checkbox checked in datatable pagination What am i doing wrong

Now i can get only one page checkbox values.

Comment: `if ($(this).is(':checked'))` should be, shouldn't it? `this.checked` is okay, just for pure JS, not jQuery. `this` in this case is invalid.

Comment: @panther; is that even possible. Am I wrong stating that `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` will only pick up checkboxes that are present in current html and also with a display different from `none`? unless of course the pagination is being implemented some other way, how can you *select* an html tag that is either not there or with `display=none`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fnGetNodes() function:

`$('input[type=checkbox]:checked', table.fnGetNodes());`

Where table is your jquery datatable.